# Efeito slide num painel sem aquele lag

Tags: vb.net, visual-basic-6, animação

Minha dúvida é a seguinte: Como eu removo aquele lag que causa quando um Panel/Button (etc) é atualizado pelo método `Controle.Update()`? É por que eu uso ele para fazer o efeito slide, mas esse efeito ta com um desempenho baixo, resultando uma animação lenta e *feia*. Aqui está meu código, considerando `Panel2` o painel que quero a animação:

```
 For x% = 0% To +200 Step +4
     Panel2.Width = x : Panel2.Update() 
 Next
```

mas não adianta em nada, quero uma animação bonita, sem lag, suave, como um menu de celular. Alguma idéia?

Comment: Boa noite CyberPotato Isto ocorre no Release ou apenas no Debug?

Comment: Sim, ocorre no modo Release também.

Answer (score 1):

Olá, CyberPotato! Testei o seu código e não apresentou lag nenhum...
O seu Panel está dentro de algum outro componente? Certifique-se de que o Panel não esteja em alguma imagem... isso gera muito lag. Não utilize a propriedade "Update" para esse tipo de tarefa. Observe o exemplo abaixo.

```
For x = 0 To 100

    Panel2.Width = x
Next
```

Comment: Ele está dentro de nenhum componente, está do lado de um `WebBrowser`, então o tempo de Resize dele também altera o tamanho do `WebBrowser`, e isso é o problema. Ele contém uns 6 botões dentro dele também, isso afeta?

Comment: Tudo que estiver dentro do seu Panel, ou em tudo que ele estiver contido vai causar lag, mas existe uma propriedade no seu Form que você pode alterar para ganhar um pouco de estabilidade. Clique no formulário e vá até a propriedade: DoubleBuffered e deixe TRUE.